why cmake install directory command installs empty directories?
this is the cmake (version 3.22.1 ubuntu) command that I use for exporting my library and it also copies those directories that does not have a matched file:
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
    OPTIONAL
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
)

how to install only those folders that have at least one matched file?

Please provide a Minimal reproducible example.

Use the target of the library instead of DIRECTORY. That should include only the files the target contains.

@AndréLehto would you please give an example?

Based on my research different versions of CMake provide different facilities for overcoming this issue.
Cmake version 3.22 proposes using PUBLIC_HEADER:
add_library(mylib STATIC ...)
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER mylib.h)
include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS mylib
        PUBLIC_HEADER
          DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/myproj
)

